# Interface class produce "Use of undefined type"

Tags: c++, c++11

ALL,

I have a following code in the foo.h:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Foo
{
protected:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
public:
    std::wstring &GetMember() { return pimpl->m_string; };
};

struct Foo::Impl
{
    std::wstring m_string;
};
```

Unfortunately this code produces an error:

```
Use of undefined type 'Foo::Impl'
```

Trying to forward declare Database::Impl results in another compiler error.

So what is the best way to fix it?

All this is in one header file.

---

EDIT:

I guess I could put the function in the actual implementations classes, but I really wanted to eliminate code duplication. However it looks like I won't have any other choice.

Comment: If  `Impl` is the same type as `Database::Impl` then this line `pimpl->m_string` need to see the full definition not just a forward declaration.  If the types are not the same please amend your post to be a [mcve].  Also the point of the PIMPL idiom is to not have the implementation in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

`pimpl->m_string;` needs the type of `pimpl` (i.e. `Foo::Impl`) to be a [complete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type), but it's defined later; only forward declaration is not sufficient, `Foo::Impl` needs to be defined before.

And I suppose you're trying to implement the [PImpl idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), which is usually used to to reduce compile-time dependencies; so you should move the definition of `Foo::Impl` and `Foo::GetMember` to an implementation file, like

```
// Foo.h
class Foo
{
protected:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
public:
    std::wstring &GetMember();
};

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
struct Foo::Impl
{
    std::wstring m_string;
};

// define Foo::GetMember after the definition of Foo::Impl
std::wstring &Foo::GetMember() { return pimpl->m_string; }
```

Comment: I'm trying to do pimpl in order to fix the warning on std::wstring being exported. Also the question is edited to give more background.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the best way to fix it?

Move the definition of `GetMember()` out to a separate translation unit (`.cpp` file).

You should do so as well for the declaration and implementation of `struct Foo::Impl`. That's at least the whole purpose of the [*Pimpl Idiom*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29).

Answer (score -1):

ALL,

Apparently there is an easier solution: move the function inside the Impl structure.

Thank you all for reading.

Comment: That defeats the use of the _Pimpl Idiom_ somehow.

Comment: @catweazle-1964, any reason why?

Comment: The whole point of the _Pimpl Idiom_ is to separate (hide) the actual implementation of an interface from it's declaration. Main reasons are: 1. You don't want to recompile all of the sources that depend on the header, when implementation changes. 2. You want to choose different translation units with your build system for different platforms.

Comment: @catweazle-1964, like I said in the OP, I chose it to eliminate the warning on the MSVC about exporting the std::wstring class object. So it is neither 1 nor 2. But I understand the point now. Thx.